# Using query IndexName, GSI in DynamoDB and not available begins_with in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am following the documentation and I see that "begins_with" is available to use in python 3.7, but I am getting the next error if I want to query a table with GSI "createdAt-index".

So here is the code that doesn't works:

```
def query_pharmaorders(date):
    table = dynamodb.Table('users')
    response = table.query(
        IndexName="createdAt-index",
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('createdAt').begins_with("2020"),
    )
    return (response['Items'])
```

Here is the error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 19)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 19\n    \t\tKeyConditionExpression=Key('createdAt').begins_with(\"2020\")\n"
  ]
}
```

Where my partition Key is createdAt.

Any ideas?

Comment: What error exactly are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the error is, but have a few ideas of what might be wrong.

According to the [docs for the query operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

> Note that if you use the IndexName parameter, you must also provide TableName.

When using the `query` operation, the partition key equality test is required and must be specified in the following format:

> partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval

While you *can* use a `begins_with` condition on the sort key, you can't do so with the partition key.  You'll need to specify the **exact** partition key when using the `query` operation.